# Is it possible to stub/mock a function call without adding an interface?

Tags: go, testing

Working with a codebase that doesn't have any interfaces in front of its Database calls, I want to test application logic that uses these functions. Is there any way to do this? Here is a simple example

```
func GetNumbers() []int {
    return []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
}

func ProcessNumbers() bool {
    numbers := GetNumbers()
    numbers = Operation1(numbers)
    numbers = Operation2(numbers)
    return Operation3(numbers)
}
```

If `GetNumbers` was a database call, is there anyway for me to stub the return type of this function, without adding a interface of on `GetNumbers`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a function:

```
func ProcessNumbers(get func() []int) bool {
    numbers := get()
    numbers = Operation1(numbers)
    numbers = Operation2(numbers)
    return Operation3(numbers)
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ProcessNumbers(GetNumbers)
...
ProcessNumbers(mockGetNumbers)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without passing in the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can stub out GetNumbers as shown below

```
var GetNumbers = func() []int {
    return []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
}

func ProcessNumbers() bool {
    numbers := GetNumbers()
    numbers = Operation1(numbers)
    numbers = Operation2(numbers)
    return Operation3(numbers)
}
```

Test code

```
func TestProcessNumbers(t *testing.T) {
    var tempGetNumbers = GetNumbers
    GetNumbers = func() []int {
        return []int{1}
    }
    defer GetNumbers = tempGetNumbers

    ProcessNumbers()
    ...
```

Comment: Is there any to do this without changing the function to a variable? There's quite a bit of functions that I have to be stubbed out.